# Replace seconds in date variable with present seconds in date

Tags: bash, shell

I get date as input to the shell script:

```sh
2021/12/21 09:09:10
```

Then, `n` seconds are added to the given date time variable, and formatted.

Date would be:

```sh
2021/12/21-09-09-11
```

But I would like to replace the time in the string with the current time.

Current date:

```sh
Thu Feb 17 09:02:57 EST 2022
```

Expected result:

```
2021/12/21-09-02-57
```

Comment: This seems less about `date` than it is about constructing an appropriate output format (like `+"2021/12/21-%H-%M-%S"`) from the input.

Comment: My bad it’s 2021/12/21-09-02-57. Editing it

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.